# A simple looking DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

While working on a physics problem, I have encountered the following DE.

$dx(y-x)+dy(k-y)=0$ where $k$ is a constant.

I have tried various approaches, like trying to concert into a linear DE form, and various other stuff in my knowledge, none if them seem to yield much.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_equation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your equation in the form $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x-y(x)}{k-y(x)}$$ now we substitute $$x=k+t,y=k+v$$ then we get
$$\frac{dv(t)}{dt}=\frac{t-v(t)}{v(t)}$$ now we substitute $$v(t)=tu(t)$$ and we get
$$t\frac{du(t)}{dt}+u(t)=-\frac{t-tu(t)}{tu(t)}$$ and this is $$\frac{du(t)}{dt}=\frac{-u(t)^2+u(t)-1}{tu(t)}$$ and this can be written as
$$\int\frac{\frac{du(t)}{dt}u(t)}{-u(t)^2+u(t)-1}=\int\frac{1}{t}dt$$
Can you finish?

Comment: In your fifth mathematical equation, RHS's numerator should contain $tu(t)$ right ?